# splitting escaped delimiters

Tags: python, regex, serialization, escaping, delimiter

**EDIT:**
Rephrased the question for better understanding.

For a project I'm doing using Huffman Compression, I need to serialize my Huffman trees.

The following text

> "bought tickets to ride down a giant spiraling water slide or run
>   through a play maze made from brightly painted plywood. All summer
>   long, the sounds of laughing"

Will produce a Huffman tree that its serialization will look like so:

```
'N57|L23, |N34|N16|N8|N4|N2|L1,made|L1,long|N2|L1,bought' \
'|L1,summer|N4|N2|L1,painted|L1,from|N2|L1,|L1,sounds|N8|N4|N2|L1,play|' \
'L1,tickets|N2|L1,All|L1,down|N4|N2|L1,brightly|L1,spiraling|N2|L1,giant|' \
'L1,ride|N18|N8|N4|N2|L1,. |L1,plywood|N2|L1,laughingreplace|L1,water|N4|' \
'N2|L1,the|L1,to|N2|L1,of|L1,through|N10|N4|N2|L1,run|L1,or|L2,a|N6|N3|' \
'L1,slide|N2|L1,maze|L1,, |L3,'
```

*note: this is the regex that separates the symbols for the tree:*

```
'(\W+)'
```

The text can also be HTML and contain the chars.

```
'|' and '\'
```

In order to escape them I change

```
'|' to '\|'
'\' to '\\'
```

When splitting the data I need to ignore the escaped characters, and only remove pipes. This becomes a problem given the next input:

```
'replace( /(^|\s)client-nojs(\s|$)/, "$1client-js$2" );</script>'
```

This is the serialized output

```
'N19|N8|N4|N2|L1,)|L1," );</|N2|L1,script|L1,client|' \
'N4|N2|L1,2|L1,js|N2|L1,(\|L1,nojs|N11|N4|L2,s|N2|L1,replace|L1,>' \
'|N7|N3|L1,1client|N2|L1,$|L1,( /(^\|\|N4|N2|L1,\|$)/, "$|L1,|L2,-'
```

Trying to split it now becomes a problem. I understood that I need to remove pipes that have even numbers of slashes before them.

```
['\\|', '|', '\\\\|', ...] Valid delimiters
['\|', '\\\|', ...] Invalid delimiters
```

This will happen when my serialized string contains a slash in its end.

```
'N54, test\\' will turn into 'N54, test\\\\|N44 ...'
```

So far I got to the point where this regex

```
r'(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\|'
```

Captures pipes with even numbers of slashes before them. However when using 
re.split() I will always have one of two problems

1. The slashes will be removed along with the pipe.
2. The slashes will be contained in their own cell in the list.

Both break my unserialization.
I need to remove the pipes, while ignoring the slashes.

If possible, I'd like to know how to do this with re.split() although I'm starting to think it's only possible with re.findall()

**EDIT**
Clarification: The split data should not have empty strings.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: This seems more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you need to expand what the *original* input is and expect output *you want* should be.

Comment: I mind less about the solution of my problem and more about the way re.split works, hence the title.
I'll add my input and expected output though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a torture test that creates and combines several small strings -- I think it should take care of most corner cases.

Mariano's `finditer()` answer passes this test with flying colors.  However, on my machine it is 15% - 20% slower than using `split()`.

However, he has a new `findall()` solution, where he modifies the string before passing it to `re`, that is faster and simpler than the `split()` solution shown here.

Note that with the recent clarification that the OP will never have any empty strings between pipe characters, the original `findall()` example proposed by Mariano (no initial string modification needed) is the best for the original poster.

Mariano's new `findall()` solution with the pre-modified string is probably best for the general case.  The `split()` is in second place, but it is what I focussed on, because it was a focus of the original question :-)

The following code works with both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
import re
import itertools
import time


def use_finditer(data):
    regex = re.compile(r'((?:[^|\\]+|\\.)*)([|])?')
    result = []

    for m in regex.finditer(data):
        result.append(m.group(1))
        if (not m.group(2)):
            break
    return result


def use_split(data):
    regex = re.compile(r'(?:\|)?((?:[^|\\]|\\.)*)')
    result = regex.split(data)
    start_delete = data.startswith('|') * 2 if data else 1
    del result[start_delete::2]
    return result


def check_split(split_func):
    values = '', '', '', ' ', ' ', '|', '|', '\\', '\\\\', 'abc', 'd|ef', 'ghi\\'
    values = [x.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('|', '\\|') for x in values]
    stuff = [], []
    for i in range(1, 6):
        srclist = list(itertools.permutations(values, i))
        for src in srclist:
            src = tuple(src)
            dst = tuple(split_func('|'.join(src)))
            stuff[dst != src].append((src, dst))

    if not stuff[1]:
        print("Successfully executed %d splits" % len(stuff[0]))
        return

    print(len(stuff[0]), len(stuff[1]))

    stuff[1].sort(key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
    for x, y in stuff[1][:20]:
        z = '|'.join(x)
        print(x, repr(z), y)


def check_loop(func, count=20):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        check_split(func)
    print('Execution time: %0.2f' % (time.time() - start))

print('\nUsing finditer')
check_loop(use_finditer)
print('\nUsing split')
check_loop(use_split)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Description:

> I need to remove the pipes, while ignoring the slashes.
>
> If possible, I'd like to know how to do this with re.split() although
>   I'm starting to think it's only possible with re.findall()

<s>It is theoretically impossible to simply use `re.split()` because, as you said, either one of the following will occur:</s> **EDIT** *(clarification after Patrick Maupin's excellent approach shown in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729163/5290909))*.

It is theoretically impossible to actually **match** the "`|`" delimiter with a *pure* regex solution so as to split on that character with Python's standard `re package`. As you said, either one of the following will occur:

1. The slashes will be removed along with the pipe.
2. The slashes will be contained in their own cell in the list.

And the reason for that is you need a backwards assertion to fail the match with odd number of escapes, while not consuming matched characters. However, [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) must be fixed-width in python (and in most regex flavours).

**Alternatives:**

The following list focuses on *pure* regex solutions that could actually match a delimiter. They are based on using a different strategy to generate the tree, or parsing with a different regex flavour.

1. Use a postfix notation por escapes:

   ```
   '|' to '|\'
   '\' to '\\'
   ```
2. Use a branch delimiter that can't be part of the *symbols* (and hence it doesn't need to be escaped).

   ```
   symbol 1{next}symbol 2{next}...
   ```
3. Call a regex library that allows [resetting the match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) (like `\K` in [regex package by Matthew Barnett](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) or in [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#resetmatchstart)). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO9zW4/1).
4. Import the [regex package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) and use regex control verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` (also implemented in PCRE). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO9zW4/2).
5. Code in [.net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) (lookbehinds allow variable-width subpatterns). [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D(%3F%3C!%5C%5C)(%3F%3A%5C%5C%5C%5C)*)%5B%7C%5D&i=%7C1%20%5C%7C2%20%5C%5C%7C3%20%5C%5C%5C%7C4%20%5C%5C%5C%5C%7C5%20%5C%5C%5C%7C%5C%5C%7C6)
6. Reverse the string before parsing, and reverse afterwards to normalize. [Demo](http://rextester.com/NWJZ46066)
7. Define a maximum number of backslashes that may precede a delimiter. [Demo](http://rextester.com/RJTZ28262).

   ```
   regex = r'(?<!(?<!\\)\\)(?<!(?<!\\)\\\\\\)(?<!(?<!\\)\\\\\\\\\\)(?<!(?<!\\)\\\\\\\\\\\\\\)[|]'
               # Up to 8 preceding backslashes
   ```

---

#### Solution 1:

- Assuming there are no empty *symbols* (tokens), or empty symbols can be ignored.

Instead of splitting, **match** each token. That is the only way to match (or assert) preceding escapes while including them as part of the token in python.

**Code:**

```
regex = r'(?:[^|\\]+|\\.)+'
data = '|1 \\|2 \\\\|3 \\\\\\|4 \\\\\\\\|5 \\\\\\|\\\\|6'
result = re.findall(regex, data)

print (result)
```

This will match any characters except `|` or `\`, and it will also match a backslask followed by any char.

**Output:**

```
['1 \\|2 \\\\', '3 \\\\\\|4 \\\\\\\\', '5 \\\\\\|\\\\', '6']
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DAO4276)

---

#### Solution 2:

If you also want to include empty tokens, you need to use capturing groups and loop each match. This is to guarantee that if the last match ended with a "`|`" it will be consider as an empty token. Otherwise, there would be no way to differentiate between `a|b` and `a|b|`.

**Code:**

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'((?:[^|\\]+|\\.)*)([|])?')
data = '|1 \\|2 \\\\|3 \\\\\\|4 \\\\\\\\|5 \\\\\\|\\\\|6'
result = []

for m in regex.finditer(data):
    result.append(m.group(1))
    if (not m.group(2)):
        break

print (result)
```

**Output:**

```
['', '1 \\|2 \\\\', '3 \\\\\\|4 \\\\\\\\', '5 \\\\\\|\\\\', '6']
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MMCYQ5060)

---

**EDIT:**

The above solutions focused on providing a clear example of how someone could approach this problem using regex. Neither the target string nor the result are parsed. However, as Patrick Maupin has shown in his [outstanding solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729163/5290909), they lack on performance. That is why I am providing another solution that proves ~30% [faster](http://rextester.com/CSD84753) than using `split()`. The main issue in the above solutions was how to treat an empty token in a leading or trailing position. This can be solved with a small *trick*.

---

### Final Solution:

To avoid checking if there's an empty token, we can prepend a "`|`" delimiter to the `data`. Therefore, we can use `findall()` with a pattern that requires a delimiter before each token.

**Code:**

```
import re

# the delimiter must precede each token
regex = r'[|]((?:[^|\\]|\\.)*)'
data = '|1 \\|2 \\\\|3 \\\\\\|4 \\\\\\\\|5 \\\\\\|\\\\|6'

# the data is prefixed with a '|' before it's passed to findall()
result = re.findall( regex, '|' + data)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['', '1 \\|2 \\\\', '3 \\\\\\|4 \\\\\\\\', '5 \\\\\\|\\\\', '6']
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JMIWOL63164)

Comment: Excellent!  Two questions: (1) is there any reason why you use `[|]` instead of `\|`  and (2) does the `+` buy any performace?  I don't think it's strictly necessary.

Comment: **1.** It's only I prefer for readability (turns out it's performing a tad faster here). **2.** You're right about that, and it's slower (I'm used to using it with an atomic group in PCRE). Thanks for the tip. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm at little confused about what you are trying to do.  You just want to split up a string of serialized data that is separated by a `|` character?

```
>>> import re
>>> data = '|1 \\|2 \\\\|3 \\\\\\|4 \\\\\\\\|5 \\\\\\|\\\\|6'
>>> re.split(r'\|', data)
['', '1 \\', '2 \\\\', '3 \\\\\\', '4 \\\\\\\\', '5 \\\\\\', '\\\\', '6']
```